# How often the videos/list statistics are updated?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm in the process of evaluating different approach for a semi-automated script that will perform actions on videos metadata, given a the number of views over time.

To put this in simple terms, whenever a video reach a certain threshold in a metric, let's says views, it will trigger certain actions.

Now to perform this operation I'll have to have a recurrent job running every, let's say, half an hour. To monitor the views.

I remember that the views in the analytics targeted query update roughly every couple of days. What about the videos/list? Is there an endpoint that can give me the "real-time" statistics for a given video?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading all I could find both in the documentation and various forums, helpdesk posts and here I decided to run some tests.

I wrote a simple script that performed requests for statistics for a video using the videos/list endpoint continuously with 1 second delay between each request.

I tried first with one of my video that I use for testing so I knew that I could reasonably be the only one watching it.

The result was spot-on. Whenever I had watched the video for (more or less) 70% of it entirety the statistics were updated.

Some issue came along when I tried with a video that was being featured in the home page of youtube. I ran this test some days ago so bear with me if I can't recall the exact numbers but it was well over 700k views.

Running the script with that video lead to some results showing not always the same number. The error was in the order of tens of views so not really relevant imho when we talk about video with hundred of thousands of views.

The reason for that inconsistency could easily be attributed to the db architecture that probably didn't propagate the data to all the replicas.

Anyway, in short the videos/list shows a reliable real time statistics data at least for views. Imho there is no reasons to not consider also the other metrics in real time as the 'views' is probably the most updated anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out [Youtube API Metrics page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#Core_Metrics) .

> This document defines the metrics that you can retrieve using the
>   YouTube Analytics API. This API supports real-time queries to generate
>   custom YouTube Analytics reports.
>
> While the YouTube Analytics API is subject to the Deprecation Policy
>   defined in the Terms of Service, non-core metrics (and non-core
>   dimensions) are not subject to the policy. In the definitions on this
>   page, any metric that is a core metric is explicitly identified as
>   such.

Comment: Thank you I already read that part but it wasn't what I needed.

I run some tests instead of seems that the 'statistics' part of videos/list is indeed update in real time-ish.